# How do wifi bulbs pair with the mobile

Tags: wifi, robotics, atmega, smartphone, smart-device

I have been working on making a commercial-equivalent smart WiFi bulb. I cannot understand how the bulb pairs with the app on smartphone and gains access to the Internet through my personal modem. The bulb cannot communicate through the personal WiFi before getting paired, as it doesn't have the credentials. I tried to experiment with my existing commercial bulb and while putting it in reset mode, noticed -

1. There wasn't any WiFi (that could be the bulb's AP) visible in the available networks list of my PC. Well, I don't know if it was a hidden network.
2. There wasn't any Bluetooth device visible in the list that could possibly be the bulb.

So I want to know how the bulb communicates with the app -

1. Does it act as AP (Access Point) and the app connects to it and gives it the credentials.
2. Else, does the bulb use any other type of communication to pair with the app.
3. Or, does it somehow just get to the smartphone and it all "mysteriously" works.

I would be happy if someone could explain the process to me. Also, the app scans for the available devices whenever I want to pair to a new device. Then, I can select the desired device and pair it. So, please also explain (if possible) how the scanning works.

> No need to get to each technical detail, I just want to know the process. I will ask later if I need the tech details.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Comment: I can't understand why no one has answered my question (I can't think of a possible way of framing it better). It's been 7 whole months and no answer. I is a bit disappointing.

Comment: You should read this article → [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)